# Flutter Expandable List View

Tags: mysql, flutter

[image: This is my Listview page]how can i put my list view into a expandable list view

```
   body: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: getData,
              key: _refresh,
              child: loading
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        final x = list[i];
                        debugPrint(x.toString());
                        return Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
```

first will be shown is the transaction ID and the vessel name and theres a arrow down that when you click it will display all the information in it

```
  child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      'Transaction ID:\t' + x["transaction_id"],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Text('Vessel Name:\t' + x["vesselname"],
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                    Text('Vessel Number:\t' + x["voyageno"],
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                    Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x["scn"],
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                    Text('Status:\t' + x["status"],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            color: x["status"] == 'pending'
                                                ? Colors.red
                                                : Colors.green)),
                                    Divider()
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Comment: see `ExpansionTile` - the docs say: *"A single-line ListTile with a trailing button that expands or collapses the tile to reveal or hide the children.

This widget is typically used with ListView to create an "expand / collapse" list entry. When used with scrolling widgets like ListView, a unique PageStorageKey must be specified to enable the ExpansionTile to save and restore its expanded state when it is scrolled in and out of view.

"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Expandable Panel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html) widget for that.